# Why is my function not loading JSON data and bringing back error undefined seemingly at random?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm using click events on menu items to update the content of a div (`#App`) and I need to populate a list that is loaded into the div with JSON data. No problems there, I run a function that performs a few actions, including populating the `<select>` list with `<option>` values, clearing the classes on the div and adding the appropriate class that is "mapped" to the ID of the nav item so I can run if statements using the current class, and updating the menu to reflect the active "page". My issue is that, seemingly at random, the list will not populate and the console logs an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

The error is referencing my output variable that appends the list with ID `schoolSelect`. I can't figure out why sometimes the function runs perfectly fine, and sometimes it does not. It seems to be at random. I would be doing this a different way if I could but I'm working within some restrictions on this application and just need to figure out why this is happening so I can move on and do more with the JSON data.

I've tried not using jquery and running an xhttp request instead but it does nothing. I've tried placing the function in different locations and running the function on different events, placing the jQuery to get the JSON data and render the list inside the click functions, I've placed it in separate functions, I can't seem to solve the issue, it appears to be randomly not firing.

#### The Code

```js
populateList = function() {
  $.getJSON("/assets/JSON/schools.JSON", function(result) {
    var schools = result.schools;
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      output += '<option>' + schools[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById('schoolSelect').innerHTML = output;
  });
}
populateTable = function() {
  $.getJSON("/assets/JSON/schools.JSON", function(result) {
    var schools = result.schools;
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      output += '<option>' + schools[0].zones[i].name + '</option>'
    }
    document.getElementById('zoneSelect').innerHTML = output;
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#alert").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#App").hasClass("alertDashboard")) {
      // Do Nothing
    } else {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("#App").removeClass()
      $("#App").addClass("container")
      $("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/AlertDashboard.html")
      populateList()
      $(".menuItem").removeClass("active")
      $("#alert").addClass("active")
      $("#App").addClass("alertDashboard")
    }
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chat").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#App").hasClass("chatDashboard")) {
      // Do Nothing
    } else {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("#App").removeClass()
      $("#App").addClass("container")
      $("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/ChatDashboard.html")
      populateList()
      $(".menuItem").removeClass("active")
      $("#chat").addClass("active")
      $("#App").addClass("chatDashboard")
    }
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#schoolInfo").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#App").hasClass("infoDashboard")) {
      // Do Nothing
    } else {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("#App").removeClass()
      $("#App").addClass("container")
      $("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/InfoDashboard.html")
      populateTable()
      $(".menuItem").removeClass("active")
      $("#schoolInfo").addClass("active")
      $("#App").addClass("infoDashboard")
    }
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savedData").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#App").hasClass("savedDashboard")) {
      // Do Nothing
    } else {
      e.stopPropagation()
      $("#App").removeClass()
      $("#App").addClass("container")
      $("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/SavedDashboard.html")
      $(".menuItem").removeClass("active")
      $("#savedData").addClass("active")
      $("#App").addClass("savedDashboard")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menuItem" style="border-bottom: none;padding:10px;text-align: 
              center;">
      <img src="/assets/images/lockout-logo-white.png" class="app-logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem active" id="alert">
      Lockdown Alert<img src="/assets/images/lock-alt.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem" id="chat">
      Chat<img src="/assets/images/comment-dots.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem" id="schoolInfo">
      School Info<img src="/assets/images/school.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem" id="savedData">
      Saved Data<img src="/assets/images/save.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container alertDashboard" id="App">
  <h1>Alert Dashboard</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 schoolList" id="listDiv">
      <div class="listHeader">
        <h5>Please select a school</h5>
        <p>Hold ctrl to select more than one school</p>
      </div>
      <select size="100" multiple id="schoolSelect" class="school_select"></select>
      <!-- <div id="infoDiv">
                <p>Drag the cursor, or hold CTRL to select multiple</p>
              </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- <img id="stage2Img" draggable="false" 
                        opacity="0.85" 
                        src="../assets/images/stage_2_up.png"/> -->
          <div class="alertStageInner">
            <div class="alertHeader">
              <img src="/assets/images/stage2Image.png" />
              <h2>Alert Level 2</h2>
              <h3>Soft Lockdown</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="alertBody">
              <p>
                Locks down school due to immediate, non-life threatening situation
              </p>
              <button id="stage2Div">Initiate Lockdown</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <img id="stage3Img" draggable="false" opacity="0.85" src="../assets/images/stage_3_up.png"/> -->
          <div class="alertStageInner" style="margin-top: 24px">
            <div class="alertHeader">
              <img src="/assets/images/stage3Image.png" />
              <h2>Alert Level 3</h2>
              <h3>Full Lockdown</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="alertBody">
              <p>
                Locks down school due to immediate, life threatening situation
              </p>
              <button id="stage3Div">Initiate Lockdown</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation

As you can probably tell, the div with ID App is the one the is affected by the functions. This process works great most of the time, but for some reason, every once in a while, again, seemingly at random, it bugs out and the schoolSelect or zoneSelect lists are not filled and I get the null error as explained before. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused why your first two functions are performing a `$.each()` over the result, when the contents of the each replace the html completely, and do not seem to use the iteration value at all

Comment: @Taplar honestly, I never even thought to remove them, that was just how I learned to do it in the first place and i guess it stuck without me thinking about it. The function operates the same so I've removed it as suggested. I'll update the code. The problem still exists, still seems random. Thank you for helping me clean up my code though.

Comment: AJAX/JSON calls can fail, e.g. if there is a glitch in the network. You should always check for success before using the result for anything.

Comment: @JohnWu If there's a network error the callback function won't be called at all.

Comment: @JohnWu I've seen it done with checks using the xhttp request but never with how I have mine setup. Could you please recommend something that may work to check? Maybe an if statement checking on the status? I'm not sure what would be the best place to start.

Comment: Where is `zoneSelect` in your HTML? I only see `schoolSelect`.

Comment: @Barmar I do have a function that runs a popup if the user loses network connectivity so that should warn me there. Also, I agree, after looking at it, the function would not run if there is a a network error. The errors are at the dynamic <select> lists. They, of course, correspond to each list: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

With the specific lines being:

document.getElementById('schoolSelect').innerHTML = output;
document.getElementById('zoneSelect').innerHTML = output;

Comment: There's no `<select id="zoneSelect">` in the HTML, so `document.getElementById('zoneSelect')` returns `null`.

Comment: Is it added by `$("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/InfoDashboard.html")`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, #zoneSelect is in one of the files dynamically loaded in $("#schoolInfo").click(function(e){...

Here's html from that file:

<h1>School Information</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 schoolList" id="listDiv">
      <div class="listHeader">
        <h5>School Zones</h5>
      </div>
      <select multiple id="zoneSelect" class="school_select"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @Barmar sorry could have waited 2 seconds and saw your follow up question, yes it is loaded in that function.

Comment: @Barmar right now it's just a list grabbing an array from the json file, it will be more later but I needed to get the data right first and fix this disappearing issue before I build the tables and such for it.

Comment: Well the most direct check is `if (output != null)` before assinging it. That is after all the error. Maybe log the `result` too, so you can see what is causing `output` to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/InfoDashboard.html")` is asynchronous, so anything that depends on its changes to the DOM needs to be done in the callback function.

```
$("#App").load("../html/Dashboards/InfoDashboard.html", function() {
    populateList();
});
```

Comment: I'm surprised it worked at all without this. Your code would only work if you were loading options into the `<select>` that's already on the page.

Comment: makes sense. Maybe because I was loading the content in first the <select> was already loaded sometimes? Not sure. Thanks a ton though, now I can move on to the next piece of this and I'm armed with more knowledge for the future. I really appreciate it.